# What is the difference between block and "hide user" Youtube

Tags: youtube

I wish to block someone on youtube but it seems that the "Block user" option has been replaced with "Hide user from channel"?

I dont want to "hide", I want to completely block.

Is it still possible to block someone? If not, why?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]!  Please [edit] this question to be a good fit for this site. It isn't a practical, detailed question about using a web application.  Please review [ask]. Then, explain what you are trying to do and the problem you are encountering.  Since you indicate the `'block...'` option was replaced by `'hide...'`, why wouldn't you use the replacement?  If there is a difference/limitation,  please explain what it is in your question.

Comment: The [edit] doesn't address the close reason.  What does it mean to "block" a user vs. the replacement function to "hide" a user.  Are they the same functionality but just renamed?  What did "block" do that  "hide" isn't doing?  Perhaps it was always "hide" just labeled "block" The point is we don't understand the actual problem you are trying to solve.  Would simply renaming "Hide user from channel"  with "Block user" solve your problem, or is there something more?